# HTML5 drag cursor

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

Pretty simple question but nothing I try works. Basically I'm using drag events (dragstart and dragend) and once I've started dragging, the cursor is always the stop sign thing (the circle with a horizontal line through it).

I've tried: Adding a class to the body and changing the cursor with css. Setting event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move', e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move'.

I've basically scoured all the google results and nothing has worked. Surely this is something that you can change. I don't want users thinking they can't drop domething somewhere because of this.

Comment: What are you dragging?

Comment: How do you select that? As far as I know you can only select text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Drag & Drop Change icon/cursor while dragging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119514/html5-drag-drop-change-icon-cursor-while-dragging)

Comment: Seen that already Adam, it didn't help. Thanks though. Halcyon, I've set the draggable attribute to true so that I can drag the div.