# Is there any way to change the cursor style when dragging DOM element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `draggable = true` DOM element, and I want to change the default cursor style when dragging this element.

Here are some codes:

```
function dragstart(e){
    element.style.cursor = 'move';
}

element.addEventListener('dragstart', dragstart, false);
```

**Please Note: Not just like custom cursor with image using css.**

Is there any way to make it?

Comment: you are using jquery ui?

Comment: What do you want the cursor to look like? Is it a custom image or existing one ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Cursor Image CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336925/custom-cursor-image-css)

Comment: @mmativ no, just native ui.

Comment: @SoorajChandran Yeah, like `cursor: move` in css :)

Comment: Do you have an event that fires when the element is dragged ?

Comment: @SoorajChandran Yes, actually I did try to  capture drag event and change the cursor style via css: `cursor: move`,  but I was failed in this way.

Comment: used jquery css function to change the cursor inside the event ? Please post some code so that i can take a look.

Comment: @SoorajChandran I have updated the question :)

Answer (score 0):

use `e.target`

```
function dragstart(e){
     e.target.style.cursor = "move";
    }
```

Try using jQuery

```
function dragstart(e){
 $(this).css("cursor","move");
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense at all.  `e` is an instance of a MouseEvent object.  `style` would be undefined in that context.  Did you perhaps mean something along the lines of `e.target` or similar?

Comment: Yes, I added jQuery in my project.

Comment: Did you check if the event is getting called ?

Comment: Yes, I added `console.log('drag event')` in `dragstart` function, and Chrome did log this message. I think Chrome just doesn't support change the cursor style when drag DOM element via `html5` native drag event.

Comment: I can't get it to work either.  It's not really the fault of the code either.  I have a suspicion that there's some weird shadow DOM stuff going on.  I tried setting the element's stlye: http://output.jsbin.com/notihesowe.  I also tried setting the root element's style *and* including `*{cursor:inherit !important}`: http://output.jsbin.com/xizujohuxu/. just to see if it created a targetable shadow DOM element, but nothing is working.

Comment: Working on it. Will come back soon.

Comment: I guess you might have already found this fiddle - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119514/html5-drag-drop-change-icon-cursor-while-dragging . Even that is not working.

Comment: I find a method that looks like can change cursor style: [mozCursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/mozCursor), but only support Firefox on Windows.