# Changing cursor while dragging HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I know there has been numerous similiar questions on stackoverflow, I've read several of them, but none provided there answers worked in my case. I want to change cursor while dragging HTML element. I tried this:

```
var startX = null;
var startY = null;
var element = document.getElementById('bla');

element.addEventListener('dragstart', onDragStart, true);
element.addEventListener('dragend', onDragEnd, true);
element.addEventListener('drag', onDrag, true);

function onDragStart(e){

  startX = e.screenX;
  startY = e.screenY;
  e.target.style.cursor = "move";
}

function onDrag(e){

    e.target.style.cursor = "move";
}

function onDragEnd(e){

    var style = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element);

  var newLeft = parseInt(style.left) + e.screenX - startX;
  var newTop = parseInt(style.top) + e.screenY - startY;

  e.target.style.left = newLeft + 'px';
  e.target.style.top = newTop + 'px';

  e.target.style.cursor = "default";
}
```

But it doesn't work. I have no idea why on earth `e.target.style.cursor = "move"` doesn't work. I tried changing it to `document.body.style.cursor = "move"`, but it doesn't work either. Any help with solving this problem with explanation why my code doesn't work will be greatly appreciated.

JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/4w20xxvp/59/

Ps. I'm looking for pure JS solution, no JQuery.
Ps2. I couldn't get answers from to work in my case. And I don't want to use custom cursor images, just standard css ones.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Drag & Drop Change icon/cursor while dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119514/html5-drag-drop-change-icon-cursor-while-dragging)

Comment: I couldn't use answers in above link to work in my case. And I don't want to use custom image (as explained in one of answers), I want to use one of css cursors (style.cursor).

Comment: Which os/browser do you use? My mac/chrome works fine with your code.

Answer (score -2):

Try to preventDefault on the other drag events. Also, you might want to consider adding a drop target that would handle dragover events.

```
document.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => e.preventDefault(), true)
```

([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4w20xxvp/65/))