# Change cursor when it is over a drop element html drag

Tags: html, css

Can you please tell me how you can change the cursor when the element is being dragged and be over the element where the dragged element can be placed?

On mac os, this cursor is named copy.

[image]

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var elem = document.getElementById(data);
  ev.target.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```css
.drop {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.drag {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  cursor: move!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="drag_elem" class="drag" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event);"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=change+cursor+drag*+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<***

Comment: @mplungjan Read the question, it's a completely different question ...

Comment: How different? Please elaborate if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119514/html5-drag-drop-change-icon-cursor-while-dragging) is not what you were looking for. I have reopened

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/effectAllowed

Comment: Does adding `cursor: copy` to your `drop` class definition not do the job?